# Is it possible to get the Minecraft 2.0 April fools update on the 6th Minecraft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been wanting to play the April fools Minecraft 2.0 version for a long time but, all the methods I have found on the internet only work on the previous Minecraft launchers. For example, one of the methods is to switch out your current minecraft.jar inside of your bin with a "minecraft2.jar" {it is called minecraft.jar as well}. But in the new launcher, the bin no longer contains the minecraft.jar. Is there any way I can get this 2.0 version on the new launcher or do I have to play it somewhere else?

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233566/is-it-still-possible-to-install-minecraft-2-0

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per ziggurism's comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple google search will throw plenty of results at you, here's one from the official Minecraft Wiki:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_2.0 (proving multiple links)

In future please do try to look for something yourself before asking here :)

Comment: I have tried that already and I don't know what to do with the files.

Comment: @LordOfMilk Sounds like you got some Googling to do. :)

Comment: @Frank This is where you end up when 'you have some googling to do'

Comment: @RyanTheLeach And?  It doesn't absolve you of putting in effort yourself beforehand.

Comment: @LordOfMilk Try running the jar files themselves. I doubt the wiki has unusable .jar files lying around on it, it's even gone to the effort of duplicating the old unworking ones. There's probably even a video or guide on how to use them there. If you're still having issues I will look at home for you.

Comment: @LordOfMilk If you're having issues still please let me know.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. (Sorry if I'm bugging you Crafter0800)

Comment: @LordOfMilk how is it not working?

Comment: I tried running the file like you said, it just automatically kicks me out.

Comment: What does "kicks me out" mean?

Comment: I won't let me enter or run the file.

Comment: please edit your answer to actually answer the question.