# Can you still install Minecraft 2.0 from the 2013 April fools joke?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would love to install the Minecraft 2.0 version and explore it for myself, but after following multiple tutorials for installing it on early versions of the launcher, it seems that none of them work for the new launcher. Is it still possible? If so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it still possible to install Minecraft 2.0?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233566/is-it-still-possible-to-install-minecraft-2-0)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes it can...**

but you will have to download the JAR and JSON files and place them manually in the `.minecraft` directory, also the download links don't point to the Mojang servers so it can't be guaranteed that the download source is safe.

Download link is in sidebar on wiki page
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_2.0

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

According to [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_2.0), *Minecraft 2.0* is, unlike many of the April Fools' joke versions, not available through the launcher and only distributed to selected people for showcasing.

You can download other April Fools' joke versions like [*20w14∞*](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_20w14%E2%88%9E) and [*1.RV-Pre1*](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_1.RV-Pre1):

[image]